# How to Make reference paths relative when chutzpah generate html harness for code coverage

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, tfs, code-coverage, chutzpah

I am using chutzpah to integrate my javascript unit tests with TFS 2015 and it's done perfectly.

**But when enabling code coverage I get errors related to file paths**

e.g.

> Error: Blanket.js encountered a cross origin request error while
>   instrumenting the source files. This is likely caused by the source
>   files being referenced locally (using the file:// protocol).

Because when chutzpah generate html file for each test file, the references paths are NOT relative :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///C:/_work/7b9b5f73/MyProject/packages/Chutzpah.4.2.3/tools/TestFiles/chutzpah_boot.js"></script>
```

I did research about how I can configure chutzpah settings to make the path relative and the best matched answer was [Customizable HTML harness generation](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Customizable-HTML-harness-generation) which says how to override the whole template not override placeholders inside default template.

**So is there any way to configure chutzpah to make reference path relative to be able to link client code coverage result with tfs.**

my chutzpah.json file looks like this :

```
{
"Framework": "mocha",
"TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
"RootReferencePathMode": "SettingsFileDirectory",
"EnableCodeCoverage": "true",
"CodeCoverageExcludes": [
    "bower_components\\*",
    "node_modules\\*"
],
"References": [
    {
        "Path": "node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "node_modules/chai/chai.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "node_modules/sinon-chai/lib/sinon-chai.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "src/client/app/mochaConstrutor.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/angular/angular.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/extras.angular.plus/ngplus-overlay.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/moment/moment.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/toastr/toastr.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/sinon/index.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/bardjs/dist/bard.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "bower_components/bardjs/dist/bard-ngRouteTester.js"
    },
     ...
],
"Tests": [
    {
        "Path": "src/client/app/admin/admin.controller.spec.js"
    },
    {
        "Path": "src/client/app/admin/admin.route.spec.js"
    },
    ...
]
}
```

[image: this is the build task on tfs]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is not a way for Chutzpah to make relative paths. However, I am currently working on a change that will let it run with a embedded web server which will make tools like Blanket work much smoother.